# roscpp relative parameter

Tags: ros, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I somehow can't manage to get or search relative parameter names.
What I do is, I launch a launch file which sets parameters.

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="test" type="test_node" name="test_node"> 
    <param name="testparameter" value="a" />
    <param name="show_windows" value="true" />
    <rosparam file="$(find test)/config/params.yaml" command="load"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

This all works, I can get and set parameters using rosparam via the shell. They are published over e.g. /test_node/orientations, /test_node/kernels/kernel_1/wavelength, /test_node/kernels/kernel_2/wavelength and so on.
Now within the test node I want to read those parameter. But when I try

```
nh_.getParam("orientations", orientations_list);
```

The parameter won't be found, I have to explicitly name the whole global name "/test_node/orientations". I have the same issue with

```
nh_.searchParam("orientations", orientations_param_name);
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to get the current namespace the node is in as a workaround?

(I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.1, 64 bit with the standard ros diamondback package from the package manager)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11098/roscpp-relative-parameter/) by [andreas](https://answers.ros.org/users/1031/andreas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2011-09-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To read parameters from the node's namespace create a private NodeHandle as:

```
NodeHandle nhPriv("~");
nhPriv.getParam...
```

Use this nodehandle to access the parameters and it will work.
This is actually not a workaround but the preferred way to do it.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems there is some confusion here about the difference between "relative" names and "private" names. You defined private parameters, which must be resolved using the "~" node handle, as Dornhege described. See [this wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Names#Resolving) for more details. Relative names can be resolved via the node's address space, but not private ones.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2